# Problema en los comentarios de VS con asteriscos automáticos

Tags: visual-studio

Mi problema es que no sé qué es lo que toque en Visual Studio Code, que al guardar entre /* */, antes no sucedía nada, es decir, se guardaba el bloque comentado, pero ahora se agregan unos asteriscos como en el siguiente ejemplo al guardar:

```
    /*
     * 
     * Hola
     * Adiós    
     * 
     */
```

¿Cómo puedo quitar eso?

¡GRACIAS!

Comment: Solo sé que en Visual Studio se puede desactivar https://stackoverflow.com/a/70206820/13419694